# Prove for x real and p integer that $\begin{pmatrix}x\\ p\end{pmatrix}=\left(-1\right)^p\:\cdot \begin{pmatrix}p-x-1\\ \:p\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, factorial, combinatorial-proofs

I have to prove for x real and p integer that
$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ p\end{pmatrix}=\left(-1\right)^p\:\cdot \begin{pmatrix}p-x-1\\ \:p\end{pmatrix}$

I have tried to remember all the properties of falling and rising factorials before starting working, i didn't find a relation of $\left(-1\right)^p\:\cdot \begin{pmatrix}p-x-1\\ \:p\end{pmatrix}$. So what i did was to use the definition of combinatorics.

1. $\frac{x!}{p!\left(x-p\right)!}=\left(-1\right)^p\:\cdot   
       \:\left(\frac{p-x-1}{p!\left(-x-1\right)!}\right)$
2. $\frac{x!}{\frac{p!\left(x-p\right)!}{\frac{\left(p-x-1\right)!}{p!\left(-x-1\right)!}}}=\left(-1\right)^p$
3. $\frac{\left(-x-1\right)!x!}{\left(x-p\right)!\left(p-x-1\right)!}=\left(-1\right)^p$
4. $x!\left(-x-1\right)!=\left(-1\right)^p\:\cdot \:\left(x-p\right)!\left(p-x-1\right)!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise
in the definition of generalized binomial coefficients,
use of product notation,
and manipulation of indices.

$\begin{array}\\
\binom{x}{p}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(x-k)}{p!}
\qquad\text{(Definition of generalized binomial coefficient)}\\
&=\dfrac{(-1)^p\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(k-x)}{p!}
\qquad\text{(Reverse the sign of each term)}\\
&=(-1)^p\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}((p-1-k)-x)}{p!}
\qquad\text{(Reverse the order of the product so } k \to p-1-k)\\
&=(-1)^p\dfrac{\prod_{k=0}^{p-1}(p-x-1-k)}{p!}
\qquad\text{(Rearrange the expression)}\\
&=(-1)^p \binom{p-x-1}{p}
\qquad\text{(Definition, again)}\\
\end{array}
$